# Ember - Using controller functions in other controller functions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create a page that shows a list of products with filtering and multiple ways of sorting the list. Rather than repeating the filtering code for each sort, I wanted to start each of the sorting methods with a call to the filtering method. I can currently filter by `name`:

```
filterText: '',
filteredResults: function() {
    var filterText = this.get('filterText');
    var regexp = new RegExp(filterText,'gi');
    var causes = this.get('model.products').filter(function(name){
      return name.get('name').match(regexp);
    });
    return causes;
}.property('filterText'),
```

However I now want to use this function in the sort methods. I've tried using [Ember.computed.sort](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort) :

```
priceAscSorting: ['price'],
sortPriceAsc: Ember.computed.sort('filteredResults', 'priceAscSorting'),
```

but it seems like it treats the first input as null if I stick it in a template. If I try calling the filter method inside the sorting method:

```
priceAscSorting: ['views'],
sortPriceAsc: function() {
  var products = filteredResults();
}
```

Ember throws a compiler error saying `'filteredResults' is not defined`. How can I access my filter methods to use in my sorting methods?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, it will take `filteredResults` computed property and return sorted result in ascending order by using `price` key.

```
priceAscSorting: ['price'],
sortPriceAsc: Ember.computed.sort('filteredResults', 'priceAscSorting'),
```

> but it seems like it treats the first input as null if I stick it in a
>   template

that means you need to check `filteredResults` computed property